# Notification only sent once from service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I am writing a service to notify every few seconds, and a notification appears once but the expected result is that it notifies multiple times, where it appears multiple times in the list.

I know that the notification id must change between multiple notifications for it to appear multiple times, so I used an AtomicInteger to increment the notification id every time the notification is sent.

At the top of the class I have the following variables declared:

```java
AtomicInteger count;
private Timer timer;
```

Then in the method onCreate() I have the following code:

```java
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        count = new AtomicInteger(0);

        final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        timer = new Timer();

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(SiteCheckService.this)
                        .setContentTitle("Notification")
                        .setContentText("You should see this notification.")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .build();
                notificationManager.notify(count.incrementAndGet(), notification);


            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 15000);
    }
```

And the onDestroy method is as follows:

```java
  @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
    }
```

I expect the notification to be sent multiple times, but it is only sent one time. There are no errors in logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the suggestions from ismail alaoui's answer to make sure the notification id is saved and I also changed the call to schedule to three parameters as follows so the TimerTask is called multiple times.

```
timer.schedule(task, 0, 15000);
```

Comment: could you please upvote my answer if it was helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to use and store your notification in a `sharedPreferences` element

```
final String Pref_Name = "Notification";
notificationPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Pref_Name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = notificationPreferences.edit();
notificationCount = notificationPreferences.getInt("notifCountNumber", 0);
```

and after your `notify()` method

```
 editor.putInt("notifCountNumber",notificationCount+1);
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: What advantage does this have over an AtomicInteger?

Comment: your notification id will be saved , and it will never be the same , instead you create  new AtomicInteger(0) every time in your onCreate which will lead to redundancy

Comment: should you change notificationCount every time the notification happens again? With the current code its seems that notificationCount is never updated.

Comment: yes it change every time the notification is call  : editor.putInt("notifCountNumber",notificationCount+1);  so the next time will get a incremented value ....

Comment: I added `notificationCount = prefs.getInt("ncount", 0);` after `editor.commit()` but the notification is still only shown once.

Comment: and how did you store the new ncount ?

Comment: editor.putInt("ncount",notificationCount+1); editor.commit();

Comment: when you debug you notice that notificationCount is getting + 1 ?

Comment: I found that the debug showed that the TImerThread was only being executed once.

Comment: this is a another reason , so even do you will fixe notificationCount you have to execute your thread multiple time